# CartThrob Database Error

Tags: cartthrob

Posting here as CartThrob say they monitor this section daily.

Clicking on "Reports" in my CartThrob Extension menu gives the following database error. Is there anything I can do about this or is it a CartThrob bug?

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

SELECT `template_id`, `template_name`, `group_name` FROM (`exp_templates`) JOIN `exp_template_groups` ON `exp_templates`.`group_id` = `exp_template_groups`.`group_id` WHERE `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `exp_templates`.`site_id` = '1' ORDER BY `group_name`, `template_name`

Filename: models/template_model.php

Line Number: 819
```

I'm on CartThrob v2.5, EE 2.8.1

Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the same thing on an EE 2.7.2 install. Did you ever find an answer to this? (Before I crank up a debugger to try and run it down)

Answer (score 1):

Is CartThrob compatible for EE 2.8.x yet? That could be an issue. But i'd just check if the *Select* the SQL is trying to do, actually exists. e.g. Does the table *exp_templates* exist. Best way of debugging it.

Comment: I don't know if it's compatible yet; I can't see anything from them about it. Would be nice if CartThrob could provide an answer. The 'group_name' column doesn't exist in 'exp_templates', and 'exp_template_groups' doesn't exist at all, which would explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar error for me. When selecting the report tab in the CartThrob CP the error is "Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'" Checking the tables **exp_templates** and **exp_template_groups** and there is not a column in either table.

```
Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

SELECT `template_id`, `template_name`, `group_name` FROM (`exp_templates`) JOIN `exp_template_groups` ON `exp_templates`.`group_id` = `exp_template_groups`.`group_id` WHERE `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `exp_templates`.`site_id` = '1' ORDER BY `group_name`, `template_name`

Filename: models/template_model.php

Line Number: 818
```

I am not about to modify line 818 of a EE file. Might if it was a cartthrob file. Accessing templates works just fine via EE Design tabs.