# CT 2.6 not working with EE 2.9.0?

Tags: cartthrob

Just installed CT 2.6 onto a EE 2.9/0 site to quickly check out the Price Modifiers Configurator FieldType and ran into some trouble. In CartThrob' section of the CP, I cannot access the Products and Reports tabs in a normal way.

---

Products tab

The Products tab does not display properly. Looks like the style sheet is gone and many of EE's CP controls are gone. And the page display several PHP Warnings.

First one

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /chroot/home/brighto1/brightorangethread.com/html/ZZiPQdPOmvcCaY/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/views/settings_form.php:80)

Filename: core/Common.php

Line Number: 446
```

Second one

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: helpers/form_helper.php

Line Number: 324
```

---

Report tab

Nothing displays. I just get

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

SELECT `template_id`, `template_name`, `group_name` FROM (`exp_templates`) JOIN `exp_template_groups` ON `exp_templates`.`group_id` = `exp_template_groups`.`group_id` WHERE `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `status` NOT IN ('closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed', 'closed') AND `exp_templates`.`site_id` = '1' ORDER BY `group_name`, `template_name`

Filename: models/template_model.php

Line Number: 818
```

Checking the tables exp_templates and exp_template_groups and there is not a column in either table. Which seems [similar to this issue](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20765/cartthrob-database-error/25256#25256).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the products channel and orders channel? It can be installed from the settings.

Comment: Thank you. Installing the product and order channels fixed the products and reports tab. So simple. I can't believe I overlooked that!!! Thank you.